# Enabling a button based on condition with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a "Save Settings" button which is of type 'image'.
I want it to be enabled only after a checkbox is checked by the user
I m using..

```
$('#btnSaveProfile').attr("disabled",true);    
$('#btnSaveProfile').click(function(){
            if ($("#rdAccept").is(':checked')) 
            {
                $('#btnSaveProfile').attr("disabled",false);
                updateProfile();// calling a function here that saves data.
            }
        });
```

This does not work, any inputs....please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the checkbox click event, try the following

```
var $btn = $('#btnSaveProfile').attr("disabled",true);   

$('#rdAccept').click(function(){
   if (this.checked) {
       $btn.removeAttr("disabled");
   }
});

$btn.click(updateProfile);
```

Comment: But this will call `updateProfile()` when the checkbox is checked, not when the (enabled) button is clicked.

Comment: @jensgram - agreed although that was not his main issue here! Changed

Comment: No, but I guess it was OP's intention :) Well, seems perfect with the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are disabling the element with id `btnSaveProfile` and then attaching a click handler, which will never get run because its disabled. You need to add a click handler to your checkbox, which will re-enable the save button.

Comment: And then still keep the `updateProfile` as `.click()` handler for `#btnSaveProfile`. E.g., `$('#btnSaveProfile').click(updateProfile);`, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/8y3qM/3/).

Answer (score 1):

`$('#btnSaveProfile').attr("disabled",'');` 
enables the button

`$('#btnSaveProfile').attr("disabled",'disabled');`
disables the button